# Detect if Object uses default toString() function or custom overwritten toString() function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function, which should check if an Object has a `toString()` function and output it or otherwise return the object. The problem is, it also triggers on plane objects  and finally returns `[Object object]` as a string which obivously looks awfull on the GUI. Is there a way to determine if an Object uses the default `toString()` method that returns the ugly `[Object object]` or has an custom `toString()` function that returns a pretty string.

Here is my current function:

```
(data: any) => (data != null && typeof data.toString === 'function') ? data.toString() : data;
```

Comment: you can check `Object.hasOwnProperty('toString')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1)** You can compare with `Object.prototype.toString`. If it is not overridden the references are equal

```js
const obj1 = {};
console.log(obj1.toString === Object.prototype.toString);

const obj3 = { toString() { } };
console.log(obj3.toString === Object.prototype.toString);
```

**2)** You can check the existence via `hasOwnProperty`

```js
const obj1 = {};
console.log(obj1.hasOwnProperty('toString'));

const obj3 = { toString() { } };
console.log(obj3.hasOwnProperty('toString'));
```

Comment: Is the second solution robust against minification and obfuscation?

Comment: They are same. String literals will not be minified

Comment: On my node.js project only [ err.toString != Object.prototype.toString ] works. Trying [ err.hasOwnProperty("toString") ] reports false. The error object is an error object returned by the "pg" library from NPM. Which is a PostGreSql library.

Comment: @KANJICODER I observed the same, which is how I ended up here, except that I was just doing something even simpler: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call("foo", "toString") => false`.

Answer (score 4):

We have two options:

1. `myObj.hasOwnProperty('toString')`
2. `myObj.toString !== Object.prototype.toString`

I think it is better to use second option, because method using `hasOwnProperty` isn't so robust. Check out this code snipped:

```js
class MyObj {
  toString() {
    return "myObj";
  }
}

class MyObjEx extends MyObj {
  something() {}
}

var a = new MyObj();
var b = new MyObjEx();
var c = new Object();
c.toString = () => "created by new Object()";
var d = { test: "test", toString: () => "created with object literal" };
var unchanged = { test: "test" };

console.log(
  "hasOwnProperty with 'native' toString method",
  unchanged.hasOwnProperty("toString")
);
console.log("hasOwnProperty object from class", a.hasOwnProperty("toString"));
console.log(
  "hasOwnProperty object from extended class",
  b.hasOwnProperty("toString")
);
console.log(
  "hasOwnProperty object from new Object()",
  c.hasOwnProperty("toString")
);
console.log(
  "hasOwnProperty object from object literal",
  d.hasOwnProperty("toString")
);

console.log(
  "compare with Object.prototype on unchanged object",
  unchanged.toString !== Object.prototype.toString
);
console.log(
  "compare with Object.prototype object from class",
  a.toString !== Object.prototype.toString
);
console.log(
  "compare with Object.prototype object from extended class",
  b.toString !== Object.prototype.toString
);
console.log(
  "compare with Object.prototype object from new Object()",
  c.toString !== Object.prototype.toString
);
console.log(
  "compare with Object.prototype object from object literal",
  d.toString !== Object.prototype.toString
);
```

Output will be:

```
"hasOwnProperty with 'native' toString method"    false
"hasOwnProperty object from class"    false
"hasOwnProperty object from extended class"    false
"hasOwnProperty object from new Object()"    true
"hasOwnProperty object from object literal"    true

"compare with Object.prototype on unchanged object"    false
"compare with Object.prototype object from class"    true
"compare with Object.prototype object from extended class"    true
"compare with Object.prototype object from new Object()"    true
"compare with Object.prototype object from object literal"    true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
o = new Object();
o.prop = 'exists';
o.hasOwnProperty('prop');             // returns true
o.hasOwnProperty('toString');         // returns false
o.hasOwnProperty('hasOwnProperty');   // returns false
```

prototype properties will return false if you check with `hasOwnProperty`

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me. The only one that worked was:

```
if (obj1.toString) {
  console.log(obj1.toString())
}
```